# Android how to change theme in activity

Tags: android, android-theme

I am new to Android, I have two theme in my res/style.xml file one is **Theme.Transparent** and another one is **AppTheme**. My requirement is I have to change the activity theme as user choose from the button actions.

How can I set themes contains in res/style.xml file. I have tried the following

```
changeTheme.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
      super.theme(......); //
    }
});
```

**super.theme** method does not accept my themes from res/style.xml file?

Answer (score 2):

It's OK to modify it with:

```
context.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light)
```

Default is `Theme_Holo`.

Comment: Please write your answer  in English!

Comment: My English is not very good, I'm afraid you don't understand.

Comment: My English is by means of translation, but I like English.

Answer (score 1):

Change the activity theme by setting it before calling super onCreate:

```
setTheme(R.style.Theme);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
```

In On click restart your activity to apply the change:

```
activity.finish();
activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_DarkActionBar);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

To change theme at button click, you can refer to the following code:

```
public static void changeTheme(final Context context) {

        int intCurrentTheme = getTheme();

              final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_theme);
        dialog.setTitle(R.string.titletheme);
        dialog.show();


        dialog.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,
                R.drawable.ic_theme);

        final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

        switch (intCurrentTheme){
            case android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_DarkActionBar:
                radioGroup.check(R.id.radio_theme_holo_light_darkactionbar);
                break;
            case android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light:
                radioGroup.check(R.id.radio_theme_holo_light);
                break;
            case android.R.style.Theme_Holo:
                radioGroup.check(R.id.radio_theme_holo);
                break;
        }

        Button btnSaveTheme = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnSaveTheme);
        Button btnCancelTheme = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelTheme);

        btnSaveTheme.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int intSelectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                int intNewTheme;
                switch (intSelectedId){
                    case R.id.radio_theme_holo_light_darkactionbar:
                        intNewTheme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_DarkActionBar;
                        break;
                    case R.id.radio_theme_holo_light:
                        intNewTheme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light;
                        break;
                    case R.id.radio_theme_holo:
                        intNewTheme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo;
                        break;
                    default:
                        intNewTheme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_DarkActionBar;
                }

                savePreference(context, "themePref", intNewTheme);
                dialog.dismiss();


         //Reload main activity                             
                 Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                 context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        btnCancelTheme.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the recreate the activity to change the current theme dynamically,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static int currentTheme = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (currentTheme == 0) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        } else {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme1);
        }

        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("AppTheme1");
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentTheme = 1;
                recreate();
            }
        });


        setContentView(button);
    }
}
```